# EventWhoIds is not writeable in apex class but working on JSForce

Tags: event

I'm having a problem with the Event object. When I insert `EventWhoIds` using JSForce, it allows me to insert. However, when I insert it through an Apex class, it won't let me and gives this error:

> Field is not writeable: Event.EventWhoIds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field `EventWhoIds` is only available at all if you have the "Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events" setting turned on in Activity Settings.

It's an [API convenience field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) of type `JunctionIdList`. It does not appear in Describe API results, although it will show up in an Enterprise WSDL if the org is configured appropriately. You can use it in JSForce because that library communicates with Salesforce via the API.

The behavior in Apex is rather odd. You can query the field in SOQL, and a `System.debug()` will show the values, but you can't read or write it using normal assignments in Apex.

You can change the underlying [`EventRelation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm) object directly. However, note that there also exist "filtered" versions of this junction object and friends, like [`EventWhoRelation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventwhorelation.htm). Those filtered entities are read-only.

Comment: Is there a way to replicate the functionality of that field via apex? It says it's a list of id's of junction objects. Can we create the junction objects ourselves?

Comment: Yeah, the underlying junction objects can be manipulated directly. I'll add a further note.

Comment: the apex limitation also means you can't use queryfactories that take as input collections of `SObjectField` as there's no `DescribeFieldResult` for any field of type `JunctionIdList`